# Traing dataset,validation dataset,testing dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, validation, testing, dataset

I am very new in Matlab and that too in Neural network.. I have 4*81 input dataset and 1*81 output/target dataset. **'divideblock'** or **'dividerand'**  randomly split the dataset into *training*, *validation* and *testing*.
My question is that... After training and simulation... how to trace the individual input dataset(training, testing, validation) which are used to train the network.

so that  i can able to find the error of the input dataset for testing, validation individually..

thanks in advance for any suggestion...

Comment: if I remember correctly you can get an errors matrix back that matches the order of your input. Or maybe I missed something in your question.

Comment: yes.. it is correct.. but say for testing we have given some portion of input randomly and also for validation and training as well. now if i want to find what were the inputs that are used in testing.. How i will find it.. <br/>I may be not up to the point in explaining my question.. because i not that good in Neural network concept..

Answer (score 1):

Use `trainInd,valInd,testInd`:

```
[trainInd,valInd,testInd] = dividerand(Q,trainRatio,valRatio,testRatio);
```

see http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/dividerand.html .

Comment: How do you then get the neural net to use these separate datasets?